# Process or Task Manager for Windows Phone 7 Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7

Are there some APIs or some way to find list of running processes, their memory usage and CPU consumption. I basically need a tool similar to "TOP" in Linux for WP7.

Comment: Nothing that will get through marketplace certification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There was a Task Manager in a pre-release version of the WP7 emulator, but that was removed early on.

Comment: I was listing down tools required for non functional testing of wp7 device. I was looking for WP7 equivalents of follwing linux tools - tcpdump, netstat, powertop, top. And also some way to simulate user click on phone. If someone is aware of any such tool/API please post in this thread. Thanks

Comment: I believe that as you progress you will find that the operating systems, their goals, structure, what they expose and how, to be pretty distinct. Trying to align tools with what you may be familiar with for desktop applications may be a frustrating exercise. I don't want to discourage, just alert you that you're comparing apples and kumquats. Best wishes for the road ahead!

Comment: Thanks Visual Stuart, what I was trying to do is find/build tools that are useful for non functional testing of mobile devices. I have worked on maemo/meego and android (basically Linux based plaforms) which have such tools. Microsoft must be having something for non-functional tests but unfortunately they don't share or open them without a price.